# combine selected columns from two tables and store it in another table in the db

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, insert-select

Hi I want to combine selected columns from two tables and store those values into another table.

example im having a table name

```
class - classname location
```

and another table

```
student - studentid, name, classname
```

Attendance - combining the two tables only selected columns.

```
i.e studentid , classname, location
```

Tell how to insert the values into my table attendance.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3):

You should use `INSERT...SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO Attendance (studentid , classname, location)
SELECT s.studentid, c.classname, c.location
FROM class c 
INNER JOIN student s ON c.classname = s.classname
```